# How to use Javascript to complete the web page effect of scrolling parallax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am a Javascript beginner. Recently, I saw a website with a scroll parallax effect. When the mouse scrolls, the pictures will overlap and move, just like this website's effect

example website:
http://www.firewatchgame.com/

```js
let scrollH;
let photo1 = document.querySelector(".photo1");
let photo2 = document.querySelector(".photo2");
let photo3 = document.querySelector(".photo3");

document.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  scrollH = window.pageYOffset;
  if (scrollH > 300) {
    photo1.style.transform = "translateY(-50px)";
  }
  if (scrollH > 300) {
    photo2.style.transform = "translateY(-100px)";
  }
  if (scrollH > 500) {
    photo3.style.transform = "translateY(-190px)";
  }
  console.log(scrollH);
});
```

```css
body{
   background-color: #AEFEFF;
   height: 2000px;
}

container{
  position:relative;
  margin-top: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
.photo1{
  position: absolute;
  top:90px;
  left:20%;
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #FFEEAD;
  transform:translate3d(0px, -10, 0px));
  z-index:1;
}
.photo2{
  position:absolute;
  top:30%;
  right:10%;
  width: 800px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #D9534F;
  transform:translate3d(0px, 390px, 0px));
  z-index:2;
}

.photo3{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  width: 900px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius:300px;
  background-color: #96CEB4;
  transform:translate3d(0px, 960px, 0px));
  z-index:3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="photo1"></div>
  <div class="photo2"></div>
  <div class="photo3"></div>
</div>
```

][1](http://www.firewatchgame.com/)

I also tried to make one myself, I will only use the easiest way!
But now I have a problem when the web page scrolls, the element does move, but I want the element to go back to the original place when the web page scrolls, but I don't know how How to achieve such an effect, I do not know if you can provide me to help modify this program.

Or if you have done a similar effect and have a better way to write it, please share it with me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
use "photo" as a class for all the photos then add this line of code

if(scrollH>300) $('.photo').css("position", "fixed")
```

Comment: Is this the way? Because the effect did not come out, I don't know if the method is wrong?
https://codepen.io/hong-wei/pen/oNGOrZY?editors=1011

Comment: The code I mentioned before was a JQuery code
You can also try this approach: 

add this line of code for every photo
if(scrollH>300) { photo1.style.position = "fixed";} else {photo1.style.position = "absolute";}